# How to give default value for file upload field

Tags: extjs

Team,

We are facing one issue where we are not able to define default value for file upload field. Basically we want to show one helper text like "Upload file" before user uploads the file.

```
xtype: 'textfield'
,inputType: 'file'
,fieldLabel: 'File Upload'
,value:'File Upload'
,autoCreate: { tag: 'input', type: 'text', size: '20', autocomplete: 'off', multiple: 'multiple' }
,name:'import_filename'
, id:'import_filename'
```

Answer (score 1):

I also met this issue and setRawValue() works.
you can render component in listeners.

```
listeners : {
                render : function(comp){
                    comp.setRawValue(fileName);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about [`emptyText`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File-cfg-emptyText). This config shows a text when there is no value in the field.

> **Note:** If you use inputType:'file', emptyText is not
>   supported and should be avoided.

Comment: Then how do I show default value. I am opening the form in Edit mode where file is uploaded before. Any other trick.

Comment: What do you mean by default value? A file that always needs to be uploaded?

Comment: Let me explain in detail.I have business flow where user will first upload the file ( This is my submit form ) . Later I am opening the form in EDIT mode where I just want to show the name of the file which was previously uploaded during submission. But it seems there is no easy way to show this.

Comment: Can you try `setRawValue()`?